# How can I know if Google Visualization is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm showing Google's charts in some web pages. But I can't assure my clients will have network access to Google: a client computer will be in the same LAN as my web server (which can access Google), but I'm not guaranteed all the clients will have access outside the LAN.

I'd like to show data using Google Charts to those clients who can access it, and a plain HTML table to those who don't.

I tried setting a variable to false, and changing it to true in a method called when the Google Visualization API is loaded:

```
var canAccessGoogleVisualizationVar = false;
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: canAccessGoogleVisualization});
function canAccessGoogleVisualization() 
{
    canAccessGoogleVisualizationVar = true;
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

How can I know from the client side if the Google Visualization is accesible or not?

---

Update: The code above didn't work because of the following code (which I didn't post before as I thought wasn't meaningful):

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() 
{
    // Check if Google Visualization is loaded
    if (!canAccessGoogleVisualizationVar) {
        alert('Can't access Google Visualization');
    }

    // The following code can be any of the samples from Google (see http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart).
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    // Add columns and values to data
    ...
    // Call new google.visualization.AnyChartBuilderFromTheAPI(<element>).draw(data);
}
```

I noticed my code didn't work because, if `canAccessGoogleVisualizationVar == true`, the `if` branch isn't taken, and if its `false`, the `function drawVisualization()` wouldn't have been executed.

So I took the if-test outside the function:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization() 
{
    // Any drawVisualization unchanged from the samples from Google (see http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#pie_chart).
}

// Check if Google Visualization is loaded at the end of this <script> </script>
if (!canAccessGoogleVisualizationVar) {
    alert('Can't access Google Visualization');
}
</script>
```

But now it's not working because the evaluation `if (!canAccessGoogleVisualizationVar)` is being executed **before** the line `google.load(?, ?, canAccessGoogleVisualization);` calls the method `canAccessGoogleVisualization()`.

How can I be sure I'm reading the value of `canAccessGoogleVisualizationVar` **after** having tried to execute the call to `google.load(...);`?

Comment: Updated the question with more information.

Comment: For what it's worth, it's possible to take the gviz js and css, and just serve it up from wherever this internal app is. Many of the charts are done client side, and thus will work fine in this manner (I've done it). Just look at the network calls going out when you load the api as normal and you can see the files you need. It's worth noting that a) the code will be minified and b) you won't get any updates to the code without manually changing it, but it may be an option :)

Comment: Thanks @peter, I'm giving it a try. The fact that the code wouldn't be updated if I don't manually change it is a plus (in this case).

Comment: Sorry... I ment @oli in my last comment, not (@)peter.

Comment: Note that serving Google's JS locally violates the TOS.

Answer (score 17):

You can try

```
function canAccessGoogleVisualization() 
{
    if ((typeof google === 'undefined') || (typeof google.visualization === 'undefined')) {
       return false;
    }
    else{
     return true;
   }
}
```